# Angularjs service keep getting object is not a function error

Tags: angularjs

I am using angular js for a project and I have two controllers. A new customer is created in the newCustomerController and I need to access the customer details in another controller. I am using the factory to perform the above request.

But I keep getting the error TypeError: object is not a function at the addCustomer function.

My factory as below

```
 app.factory('mySharedService',function($rootScope){
    var sharedService = {};

   sharedService.customer = {};

   sharedService = {

       prepLoadAddress : function(customer){
        this.customer = customer;
        $this.loadAddress();
      },

      loadAddress : function(){
        $rootScope.$broadcast('handleLoadAddress');
      }
   };
   return sharedService;
 });
```

My first controller as below

```
function newCustomerController($scope,$http){
     $scope.name = "John Smith";
     $scope.email = "John Smith";
     $scope.contact = "John Smith";
     $scope.address = "John Smith";
     $scope.comment = "John Smith";
     $scope.archived = 0;

     $scope.addCustomer = function() {

        $http({
            method: 'POST',
            url: '/customers/createCustomer',
            params: {
                name: $scope.name,
                email: $scope.email,
                contact: $scope.contact,
                delivery_comment: $scope.comment,
                archived: $scope.archived
            }
        }).success(function(result) {
            $scope.name = "";
            $scope.email = "";
            $scope.contact = "";
            $scope.address = "";
            $scope.comment = "";
            $scope.archived = 0;

            mySharedService.prepLoadAddress(result);
        });
    };
}
```

This controller creates the customer. Upon success, it will set the scope for the customer in another controller. My controller as below

```
function bController($scope, $http) {
$scope.customer = {};
    $scope.load_customer = function() {

    if ($scope.customer_id != null) {
        $http({
            method: 'GET',
            url: '/customers/customer',
            params: {
                id: $scope.customer_id
            }
        }).success(function(result) {
            $scope.customer = result;
            $scope.address_id = result.address.id;
            $scope.address = result.address;
        });
    }
};

$scope.$on('handleLoadAddress',function(events,customer){
    $scope.customer = mySharedService;
});
};
```

Did the inject as well

```
newCustomerController.$inject = ['$scope','mySharedService'];
newWaypointController.$inject = ['$scope','mySharedService'];
```

Anyone can help me with this? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all

```
app.factory('mySharedService',function($rootScope){
  var sharedService = {};

  sharedService.customer = {};   

  sharedService = {          <-- here you assign new object to sharedService, so there is no sense in previous two lines.

    prepLoadAddress : function(customer){
      this.customer = customer;
      $this.loadAddress();
    },

    loadAddress : function(){
      $rootScope.$broadcast('handleLoadAddress');
    }
  };
  return sharedService;
});
```

I don't see in your controllers injection of mySharedService

```
function newCustomerController($scope,$http, mySharedService){
function bController($scope, $http, mySharedService) {
```

And here you probably want to assign customer?

```
$scope.$on('handleLoadAddress',function(events,customer){
   $scope.customer = mySharedService.customer;
});
```

Comment: Thanks!. Those changes were what I miss out on